# Can I skip dialogues and still get the achievements?

Tags: achievements, diablo-iii

There is a class of achievements in Diablo 3 that requires you talk to the townsfolk such as [this one](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/bewitched).

Does it require you to sit there and wait for the dialogue to finish or can you skip them and still get the achievements?

Comment: Did you manage to start playing already? I'm still waiting D:

Comment: No. Hence the question lmao :D

Comment: Why not just click `X` on all those message boxes?

Comment: If I could log on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the conversations (by pressing the X to the dialogue boxes, pressing the space key or the escape key) and still get the achievements, ONLY after you've listened to the dialogue **for at least 8 seconds**

This is now proven through playing through the game and regularly checking for the achievement updates.

Comment: You can also press the spacebar to skip a conversation piece. I wonder what happens if you opt out of the conversation after it started by hitting escape or just walking away.

Comment: Will have a go at it.

Comment: You can also skip the cutscenes by pressing escape.

Answer (score 8):

Contrary to the current accepted answer, it appears that **you do not need to listen to dialogue for a minimum of 8 seconds**. I tested this today and made a quick video of my results, [see it here](http://youtu.be/_TVJDQvUJWI).

In summary, you can quickly skip through all of the dialogue and still get credit toward the achievements.

Edit: I have run more tests, here is a link to a Youtube video where I skip through 18 conversations of varying lengths at full speed and get credit for all of them. It's not exactly a riveting video, but I think that it sufficiently supports my answer. [Here is the video](http://youtu.be/KMCnhVS5wFk) (the footage is sped up to make the video shorter).

Comment: It is interesting, because I tested it again and it seems that sometimes it gives you credit for immediately skipping the dialogue and sometimes it doesn't. Would it be possible that it depends on factors like the length of the dialogue?

Comment: @JamesJiao That could be, we shall have to do more SCIENCE!

Comment: Know a way to reset an achievement? It's getting harder and harder to test now as I have almost got all the conversation achivements!

Comment: @JamesJiao There are separate achievements for each region, changing to Europe or Asia would give you a clean slate. I don't know of any other methods.

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen to the whole conversation to get the Achievement for conversations, atleast that is how I did it. However it doesn't matter how quickly you listen to the whole conversation, so you can spam space through it all and still get it. I know this for a fact since I went through and quest jumped to get some conversation options I had missed.

Comment: Nope, you don't have to. 8 Seconds are enough to get you each part of any conversation achievement.